# Display all ids in a PHP Binary Tree

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, binary-tree

I am trying to find all id's of child elements in a binary tree under main user. My code is based on php, wordpress and I am using mysql tables.
I am using two tables one is wp_users and another is wp_binary.
wp_users is storing normal users information. wp_binary is storing tree values.

Please run following code snippets to see mysql tables.

```html
<table border="1">
<tr><td colspan=2>Table wp_users</td></tr>
<tr><td>ID</td><td>user</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>A</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>B</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td>C</td></tr>
<tr><td>4</td><td>D</td></tr>
<tr><td>5</td><td>E</td></tr>
<tr><td>6</td><td>F</td></tr>
<tr><td>7</td><td>G</td></tr>
<tr><td>8</td><td>H</td></tr>
<tr><td>9</td><td>I</td></tr>
<tr><td>10</td><td>J</td></tr>
<tr><td>11</td><td>K</td></tr>
<tr><td>12</td><td>L</td></tr>
</table><table border="1">
<tr><td colspan=4>Table wp_binary</td></tr>
  <tr><td>ID</td><td>UID</td><td>RID</td><td>leg</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>1</td><td>right</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>1</td><td>left</td></tr>
  <tr><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>2</td><td>left</td></tr>
<tr><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>2</td><td>right</td></tr>
  <tr><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>3</td><td>left</td></tr>
<tr><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>3</td><td>right</td></tr>
<tr><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>4</td><td>left</td></tr>
<tr><td>8</td><td>9</td><td>4</td><td>right</td></tr>
</table>
```

Structure of my tree is as below.

```html
<pre>  
        A
        |
     |------|
     B      C
     |      |
   |---|  |---|
   D   E  F   G</pre>
```

I want to get values of all ids of members under my main user(which is at top most position of tree. User "A")
My code is as like below.

```
<?php
 $lau_id=$_SESSION["user_id"];
 function find_user($x){
 global $wpdb;
 $lau_id=$x;
 $lau = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_binary WHERE RID='".$lau_id."'" );
 foreach($lau as $laus)
 {
 $lau_id=$laus->UID;
 }
 return $lau_id;
 }
 while($lau_id = find_user($lau_id)) { 
 $lau_info = get_userdata($la_id);
 $lau_login=$lau_info->user_login;
 echo($lau_login."<br />");
 if($la_id==$lau_id){
 break;
 }
 $la_id=$lau_id;
 }
 ?>
```

My question is that if I know ID from table wp_user of user A then how do I write code to display ids of all members under user A. Please help me. My above code is not correct. Please help me by either writing new code or please edit my code in correct form.

Comment: You have a function. In the function you loop. In the loop you assign each value to a variable, overwriting the previous assignment. After the loop you return the variable, which then contains only the last item. So basically the whole loop is obsolete and you only use the last item..

Comment: Yes that is what I do not want. I think if I could pass each value from foreach loop to while($lau_id = find_user($lau_id)) { then it may solve it. Can you tell please how could I get all values of ids of all members under main user?

Comment: Please help I need your help. Please tell how to find it?